# Excel integer date-time reference and usage

Tags: excel, datetime

I'm currently performing analysis on some data. Basically, sorting different product by certain variables, all this in different time frames (product flow every 30 minutes).

My date and time column looks like this: 2.01701E+11 (201701262230).

How do I refer to it?

Thank you.

---

Thank you for the prompt answer, but I still don't quite get how to use it. I've tried but failed.

Basically imagine I have a column with products (A, B, C, D) and next to them a column with daytimevalues that start at 13 o'clock on a certain day (201701241300) and end at 11PM the same day (201701242300). The range changes each 30 minutes.

I am trying to count all product A on the 24th of January at 13:00, and then at 13:30 and so forth:

the formula would go something like this:
=COUNTIFS(Data[Product_type], "A", Data[day_hour], ??????????)

Comment: What do you want to do with the values?  If you just want to sort, you can probably use the values as is.  If you need them as Excel-recognized date/times, then you could use string functions to format and split the underlying value into something Excel would recognize.

Comment: Basically I want to use COUNTIFS to count all the products that were for example sorted at 1 o'clock on the 24th of January 2017 (201701241300)

Comment: Then convert them to date/times and use your formula.  Edit your question to show what you have tried, and if you have a problem.

Comment: can you add a sample data and desired output?

Comment: Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and, **more importantly in this case**,  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]`=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"0000-00-00  00\:00"))` this  fromula will get you the date.
`=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"0000-00-00  00\:00"))` this formula will give you the time.

A1 is the cell containing the input value

In the Image the column C and D contains the above mentioned formula...

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,F3,$C$2:$C$10,$G$1,$D$2:$D$10,(">=13:00:00"),$D$2:$D$10,("<14:00:00"))
```

you can use the above formula in cell G3 to get desired output...similarly you can use it to get other values as well.

Comment: Could you please help me a bit more?

Comment: I posted a message attached to my first message.

Comment: Add a sample data and desired result

Comment: I uploaded an image. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have added an image.... Check the formula...And edit it as per your requirement....If you have any doubt regarding the execution of the formula revert back....I will explain further

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a direct reference, but this is ok for now.

Comment: Direct reference cannot be achieved if you are going to use countifs function....I suggest a you create a UDF for that

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW99w.png)

You can see the situation here. Basically I have the dates under that form. I need to count the countries by occurence in time, every have  hour in a given day.

Comment: The dates look like this in the formula bar: 201701241330, 201701241400 etc.